# Event when data sent in Twisted Python?

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

I'm writing a TCP/IP server using the Twisted framework.  I am sending a very large stream of data, in small chunks.  So I need to know when the data I've sent has made it through Twisted's buffers and into the OS, and the OS is ready for some more data.  Is there a way to be notified when this happens?

I am doing this to measure network throughput, so I'm generating an unlimited amount of data.

If I was using normal sockets (not Twisted), the answer would be to use poll() with POLLOUT for that, but I want to do this using Twisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

`self.transport.registerProducer(AProducer(), True)`, and then

```
from zope.interface import implementer
from twisted.internet.interfaces import IPushProducer
@implementer(IPushProducer)
class AProducer:
    def pauseProducing(self):
        "stop producing data; buffers are full"
    def resumeProducing(self):
        "resume producing data; buffers have space"
```

You can find more in [the Twisted documentation for consumers and producers](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/producers.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are so called push and pull producers.  You need push producer, obviously :)

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.1.0/core/howto/producers.html